# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.zseni.weatherapp.core.data.apicontents.WeatherDto

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I get the error when I run my app using the weather API. This is the code for the API my data class that calls the required data from the API, weatherDto and my JSON Class.
It also shows these errors in my logcat:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for spes
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter class for class com.zseni.weatherapp.core.data.apicontents.Hourly.

My App runs but nothing from the API is shown on the screen just a blank screen.

My Data Class

```
data class WeatherDto(
   @field:Json(name = "hourly")
   val weatherData: Hourly,)
```

My weatherDataDto

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class WeatherDataDto(
    @Json(name = "elevation")
    val elevation: Double,
    @Json(name = "generationtime_ms")
    val generationtimeMs: Double,
    @Json(name = "hourly")
    val hourly: Hourly,
    @Json(name = "hourly_units")
    val hourlyUnits: HourlyUnits,
    @Json(name = "latitude")
    val latitude: Double,
    @Json(name = "longitude")
    val longitude: Double,
    @Json(name = "timezone")
    val timezone: String,
    @Json(name = "timezone_abbreviation")
    val timezoneAbbreviation: String,
    @Json(name = "utc_offset_seconds")
    val utcOffsetSeconds: Int
)
```

Hourly data from my API

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Hourly(
    @Json(name = "pressure_msl")
    val pressure: List<Double>,
    @Json(name = "rain")
    val rain: List<Double>,
    @Json(name = "relativehumidity_2m")
    val humidities: List<Double>,
    @Json(name = "temperature_2m")
    val temperatures: List<Double>,
    @Json(name = "time")
    val time: List<String>,
    @Json(name = "weatherCode")
    val weatherCodes: List<Int>,
    @Json(name = "windSpeed")
    val windSpeeds:List<Double>

)
```